How to execute a program with all output redirected to a file and then read the file and display it
I need to execute un program in TCL, this program is quite long to execute and during its execution I need to display the log generated by the program. Unfortunately for an unknown reason, this program can't have their outputs captured by TCL using the classic way (fileevent, etc.) : A specific program can't have their output being captured by TCL on windows whereas the linux version is working great
so the workaround would be to execute the program and redirect all output of the program inside a file and during the program execution the same tcl script would read the file generated.
All my trials are currently KO because when file redirection is done fileevent no more works and generates an error.
I need to be able to launch the program in TCL with output redirected in a file, I need TCL not to wait the end of the program execution and the TCL need to start reading the file that is being written by the tool. It would be great also that TCL could be still able to know that the program has finished its execution (I know how to do it using open + fileevent but is seems that there is a problem if I use this method + output redirection).
using command line windows : D:\app\iao\qverify.exe -od output_files -l qverify.log -c -do run_questalint_top_fb_a429_tx.do > test1.txt
it works great and all output are redirected inside a file. but using TCL I don't succeed

To redirect output to a file in Tcl, use:
exec programName >theOutputFileName

when starting it. In some cases, you need to also pass options to the program to make it cooperate; that's very program-specific so you have to consult the documentation for it to know for sure. The redirect above certainly asks for the output to go there.
If you are working with a pipeline, the syntax is:
open |[list programName >theOutputFileName]

Once created, that file is just a conventional file. It will be text if the other program produced text, and binary if the other program produced binary data. Read it by opening it and using gets and/or read.

the problem I have when doing this method using "open" + redirecting output to a file is that I have a tcl error when I do the fileevent procedure. the error indicates that output are redirected and fileevent don't like it. if I dont use fileevent, I don't know how can I be aware that the program is terminated. Even if I start reading the file "theoutputfilename" before the end of the execution, i still need to monitor that the program execution is over

here the message I have :
can't read output from command: standard output was redirected
while executing
"open "|$cmd > test.txt" r"
(procedure "exec_questalint" line 40)
invoked from within

this method work for redirection but it only redirect error... I don't know how to redirect everything using tcl : set appli [open "|$cmd 2>@ $logfile" r+] with logfile defined like this : set logfile [open "./questa_lint_error.log" w+]

and if I try to use exec + output redirection, then I have the following error : couldn't execute "D:\app\iao\qverify.exe -od output_files -l qverify.log -c -do E:\run_questalint_top_fb_a429_tx.do >text.txt": No error

even exec without output redirection generates the same error message...

ok, problem resolved with exec, I need to use the following trick: set toto "$cmd >test.txt" and then eval $toto. now the program start but the file is always empty :-( whereas the same command executed from windows works and fill the file where output are redirected

If this works in a windows command shell:
D:\app\iao\qverify.exe -od output_files -l qverify.log -c -do run_questalint_top_fb_a429_tx.do > test1.txt

Then you could wrap it in TCL this way:
exec cmd /C "D:\app\iao\qverify.exe -od output_files -l qverify.log -c -do run_questalint_top_fb_a429_tx.do > test1.txt"

